# Is it possible to restart docker container from inside it

Tags: docker, selenium-grid

I'd like to package Selenium grid exrtas into a docker image.

This service being run without using docker container can reboot the OS it's running in. I wonder if I can setup the container to restart by Selemiun grid extras service running inside the container.

Comment: In which case do you/want need to restart? The container can communicate with the daemon directly if the daemon is started with the right arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Selenium Grid, but as a general idea: you could **mount a folder from the host as data volume**, then let Selenium write information to there, like a flag file.
On the host, you have a **scheduled task / cronjob** running on the host that would check for this flag in the shared folder and if it has a certain status, you would invoke a `docker restart` from there.

Not sure if there are other more elegant solutions for this, but this is what came to my mind adhoc.

**Update:**

I just found this on the Docker forum:

https://forums.docker.com/t/how-can-i-run-docker-command-inside-a-docker-container/337

> I'm not sure about CoreOS but normally you can manage your host
>   containers from within a container by mounting the Docker socket.
>
> Such as
>
> ```
> docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ubuntu:latest sh -c "apt-get update ; apt-get install docker.io -y ;
> ```
>
> bash"
>
> or
>
> https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/abh1nav/dockerui/

Comment: I get you, thanks! Seems I should investigate the way selenium extras restarts OS. Maybe I'll be able to change it the way you proposed

Comment: Yes, there is: the container itself can send a request to the daemon to be restarted.